# Is it possible to close a div tag right before closing the body tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to use jQuery (or similar) to add a `</div>` right before the `</body>`?

I am working on a large piece of software written in php, hundreds of files. DO not know why, but the author just used a header.php file, while deciding to close the page in each file (`</body></html>`).

For reasons that I am not going to explain to cut the story short, I cannot edit every single file.

I've added the opening

```
<div class="container" role="main">
```

in the header.php file, and I wonder if it is possible to close it before closing the body using javascript so that the resulting html would be:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" role="main">
    </div><!-- added via javascript -->
</body>
```

I've googled and "stackoverflowed" without finding anything.
Thanks for your hints

---

Sorry, I am neihter able to post comments (I always receive the same error message "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified"), nor to edit my post. So I am going to write here my answer to all your precious comments first, then I will close my post as duplicate since I believe that the post cited by Jono20201 answers my question... and says NO!!!

I've already tried jQuery .append and .appendTo. But reading the above mentioned thread, which unfortunately did not popped out in my research, I've understood that doing what I want to do is impossibile via javascript (so definitely @Scuzzy is right). So I've two options: 1. using ob_start() and ob_get_contents as suggested by @Jonathan Kuhn; 2. edit each and every file. I think I should go for the second, which is a bit more time consuming but, to me, grants the best result, since the code will be in a good shape (every tag properly closed).The project is a collab one, so I need to be clear

Comment: The problem I see you having is the browsers interpreting this differently in the DOM because of the missing closing tag. Could be as simple as `$("body").append("</div>")` though?

Comment: You could do it with php using output buffering. `ob_start()` at the top of the script and at the end `ob_get_contents()` and then just str_replace to add in the closing div tag. If you need to run some file at the end of every request (like you are not routing through a single index file that includes stuff), php does have an auto append feature.

Comment: Yeah I'd say it's far too late to be correcting the DOM with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").append("</div>");
});
```

But I worry that different browsers will handling the 'invalid' html differently causing issues.